# How to make promtail read new log written to log file which was read already?

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I have a very simple test setup. Data flow is as follows:

```
sample.log -> Promtail -> Loki -> Grafana
```

I am using this log file from microsoft: [sample log file download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=37003)

I have promtail config as follows:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp\positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: testing_logging_a_log_file
    static_configs:
        - targets:
            - localhost
          labels:
            job: testing_logging_a_log_file_labels_job_what_even_is_this
            host: testing_for_signs_of_life_probably_my_computer_name
            __path__: C:\Users\user\Desktop\sample.log
  - job_name: testing_logging_a_log_file_with_no_timestamp_test_2
    static_configs:
        - targets:
            - localhost
          labels:
            job: actor_v2
            host: ez_change
            __path__: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Actors_2.txt
```

Loki config:

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 5m
  chunk_retain_period: 30s
  max_transfer_retries: 0

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2018-04-15
      store: boltdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 168h

storage_config:
  boltdb:
    directory: C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp\loki\index

  filesystem:
    directory: C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp\loki\chunks

limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: True
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h

chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: false
  retention_period: 0s
```

The sample files are read properly the first time. I can query WARN logs with: `{host="testing_for_signs_of_life_probably_my_computer_name"} |= "WARN"`

Problem arises when I manually add a new log line to the `sample.log` file. (To emulate log lines written to the file)

```
2012-02-03 20:11:56 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 42334089511
```

This new line is not visible in Grafana. Is there any particular config I must to know to make this happen?

Comment: Hi Jeeva, The new log line should be automatically shipped to Loki and reflected in Grafana. AFAIK there need not be done anything explicitly. Your promtail configuration looks all good to me.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the network, if you remove the loki port and don't configure any network you can access it by putting http://loki:3100 in your grafana panel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's weird, when I append a line to a existed log file, it can't be seen in grafana explore.but ....try to do it again , append one more line, now the previous line is show in grafana

it happens when you using notepad, works well on notepad++